# JavaScript - How to make an array of values out of an key and value array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the next key:value array -

```
[["key1",76],["key2",73],["key3",59],["key4",52],["key5",37],["key6",7],["key7",5],["key8",5],["key9",3],["key10",2],["key11",2]]
```

And I would like to make an array out of it but only with the values of it and also to keep the order of the values, meaning the new array should be like this -

```
[76,73,59,52,37,7,5,5,3,2,2]
```

I've tried to find a way to do that but failed miserably,

Thanks in advanced for any kind of help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var arr1 = [["key1",76],["key2",73],["key3",59],["key4",52],["key5",37],["key6",7],["key7",5],["key8",5],["key9",3],["key10",2],["key11",2]];
var arr2 = arr1.map(function(v){ return v[1] });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [["key1",76],["key2",73],["key3",59],["key4",52],["key5",37],["key6",7],["key7",5],["key8",5],["key9",3],["key10",2],["key11",2]];

var result = [];

arr.forEach(function(val,index){
    result.push(val[1]);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res_list = [];
var ori_list = [["key1",76],["key2",73],["key3",59],["key4",52],["key5",37],["key6",7],["key7",5],["key8",5],["key9",3],["key10",2],["key11",2]];

for( var i=0, len=ori_list.length; i<len; i ++ ) {
    res_list.push( ori_list[i][1] );
}
```

Comment: There's no `append` function on arrays

Answer (score 0):

No need of looping through the array, you can use `regex` in your case to extract all the values from the nested array.

```js
var target = [["key1",76],["key2",73],["key3",59],["key4",52],["key5",37],["key6",7],["key7",5],["key8",5],["key9",3],["key10",2],["key11",2]];

var result = target.toString().match(/\b\d+\b/g);

console.log(result);
document.write(result);
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret `result` is array. You can run the code and check console for output

Comment: Sorry, you're right, misread. It's still horrible to convert to a string

Comment: @DenysSéguret Just wanted to add it as another way to achieve the result. I could have use loops, but that would be duplicate of other answers